# Scraping a dynamic data-table in python through AJAX request

Tags: python, json, ajax, web-scraping, datatable

I would like to implement a demo backend script in python in order to scrape the list of document paths through the URL. If I try to handle through the basic request with urllib.request, it does not return the content of the datatable. It is just returned an empty content as below. Hence, the content of the data table might be captured with the AJAX request in this scenario. The example code which is taken from homepage of the actual website (Actual Page). I think main issue here might be token side. How can I handle the python side in order to capture the content of the dynamic datatable?

The code I wrote on python side (Current python code) can not handle this request and returns "The page has expired due to inactivity."

Any suggestions, directions ?

**Current python code:**

```
from requests import Session
session = Session()
session.head("mainpage")
response = session.post(
    url= 'apiurl/getviewdatatable',
    data= {
        'name' : 'name',
        'documentPath' : 'documentPath',
    }           
)

print(response.text)
```

**Actual Page: mainpage**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#posts').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "apiurl/getviewdatatable",
                    "dataType": "json",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "data": {
                        _token: "5uC8cmrJRYnn2gB4TCU9EFj0wjgA8BtmqqO64Uk1",
                    }
                },
                "columns": [
                                            {
                        "data": "name"
                    },
                                        {
                        "data": "documentPath"
                    },

                ],
                'createdRow': function (row, data, index) {
                    //
                    // if the second column cell is blank apply special formatting
                    //
                    $(row).addClass('table-row');

                },
                "language": {
                    "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Turkish.json"
                },
                "rowReorder":{
                    selector:'td:nth-child(2)'
                },
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your python post request parameters.

First of all let me explain what the actual page is doing.
There is a table component which is a part of [datatables](https://datatables.net/) library.

In this page datatables is filling up with an ajax source.
ajax calls are handled by datatables libraries internal scripts. 
You can see the example page of ajax source of datatables in this link https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html

But here in your code ajax call is more detailed. But even like that you can understand according to the example in the link above ***columns*** are not parameters of the ajax call. 
Here is the parameter part of the POST ajax call

```
"data": {
    _token: "5uC8cmrJRYnn2gB4TCU9EFj0wjgA8BtmqqO64Uk1",
 }
```

So when you are sending a post request to this apiurl you have to send the post request same as the page you want to scrape

**Here is the correct post request with python:**

```
from requests import Session
session = Session()
session.head("mainpage")
response = session.post(
    url= 'apiurl/getviewdatatable',
    data= {
        '_token' : '5uC8cmrJRYnn2gB4TCU9EFj0wjgA8BtmqqO64Uk1'
    }           
)

print(response.text)
```